# Symfony : How to get right mime type on ppt and pptx

Tags: symfony, mime-types

I want to import a PowerPoint file to my Symfony application.
I allowed these mime types into a whitelist parameter.

```
co_upload_white_list: 
    - "image/*"
    - "application/pdf"
    - "application/x-pdf"
    - "application/msword"
    - "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"
    - "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    - "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"
    - "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    - "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    - "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"
    - "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
```

This code work fine but the mimetype returned by Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser.php at $file->getMimeType() : application / octet-stream but it should be application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

```
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\Naming\NamerInterface;

class UploadListener implements NamerInterface
{
[....]

    public function onValidate(ValidationEvent $event)
    {

     /**
     * $file is oneup/uploader-bundle/Uploader/File/FilesystemFile.php
     */
    $file = $event->getFile();
    $mimeType = $file->getMimeType();
    $fileSize = $file->getSize();
    $ext = $file->getExtension();

    $hotel = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('hotel');
    $locale = ($hotel->getUserLocale()) ? $hotel->getUserLocale() : 'en';

    if (explode("/", $mimeType)[0] != "image" && !in_array($mimeType, $this->uploadWhiteList)) {

        $this->messenger->error("MimeType invalid: %mimeType%", ['%mimeType%' => $mimeType], $locale);
        throw new HttpException(400, "File type invalid, mimetype is '$mimeType', allowed=".json_encode($this->uploadWhiteList));
    }
[...]
}
```

Is there a way to get the right kind of mime type?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [mime_content_type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

```
echo mime_content_type("example.ppt");
```

Output:

> application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

[Try this](https://repl.it/repls/ApprehensiveAwfulActivemovie)

Using symfony this works for me (symfony 3.4);

```
    $filepath = "/tmp/example.ppt";
    file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents("https://sample-videos.com/ppt/Sample-PPT-File-500kb.ppt"));
    $file = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($filepath);
    echo $file->getMimeType();
```

Same output:

> application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

Comment: Thanks.

I'll complete my code, i get back the $event from ValidationEvent.
My class is event listening on 
            - { name: "kernel.event_listener", event: "oneup_uploader.validation", method: "onValidate" }

Comment: Add: $file is a oneup/uploader-bundle/Uploader/File/FilesystemFile.php that extends  UploadedFile and implements FileInterface.

And getMimeType()  return application/octetStream